# how to implement server client protocol using c

Tags: network-programming

I have a project to implement server client protocol in our lab. I want to explain my project as there would two or more host and one administrator. on administrator screen all the information about host computer which log in by host users would be displayed as a icons. on clicking on particular icon administrator can see the all information about system details like (log in history etc.), and administrator can access the host screen remotely or can handle mouse of host users.

thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working with sockets and client-server networking over TCP/IP, I recommend reading Beej's Guide to network Programming: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/, free on the web.

Comment: what should be the system design and from where i should  start this project?